# Problems with authentication using AWS Amplify

Tags: aws-amplify

I initially set up my app with aws amplify. I created a cognito user pool, created a user, logged in, and did some stuff. When the session expired, I could not log back in and the app seems to be completely unaware that authentication was ever set up.

I tried to simply redo the authentication using amplify update auth, but I honestly don't understand half the questions presented to me and I can't find a simple explanation for them.

For example, the system asks for a redirect signin URI and wants a full URL - which can be http://localhost/something or it can be https://www.myapp.com. You can then add multiple uris. I really don't understand this. Shouldn't this be one URL like "/profile" that the user is sent to after logging in regardless of being on localhost or the deployed app?

If using facebook and google logins, the facebook app ID and google app ID are asked for multiple times. Why?

There seems to be no way to back up if you make a mistake?

I don't understand any of this? Why is auth no longer working? Where is an explanation of what some of these questions mean?

If I run Amplify add auth, I get the following result ...

```
amplify add auth
Auth has already been added to this project. To update run amplify update auth.
```

If I then run the app and try to log in, I get the following error in the console...

```
25:02.198 AuthError - 
        Error: Amplify has not been configured correctly. 
        The configuration object is missing required auth properties.
        This error is typically caused by one of the following scenarios:

        1. Did you run `amplify push` after adding auth via `amplify add auth`?
            See https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#amplify-project-setup for more information
```

I'm just kind of lost. Is amplify set up for authentication or not? Where can I check to make sure that it's connecting to the correct user pool? How do I even go about diagnosing this?

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: Not really. I had to redo the app-sync process from the beginning

Comment: Ya, i did the same :(